# crossrider: specify sites to show page action in

Tags: popup, crossrider

I would like to know if there is a way to specify for a page action to be shown only on some sites through crossrider and if so how to use it.

I have tried using "appAPI.pageAction.setPages" but the icon is shown on every page and the popup is not loaded unless I use appAPI.pageAction.setPopup.

If you want to see the current state of the extension the id is 56885. I am currently leaving it specified from what I understand to only show on the cross rider site and show the example text as popup but that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to use is [appAPI.pageAction.setPages.setPages](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.pageAction-method-setPages) setting the icon and page filter in the options passed to the method. In your extension, I can see that you are using [appAPI.pageAction.setResourceIcon](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.pageAction-method-setResourceIcon) which has the effect of setting the icon on **every page** and hence your issue.

To achieve your goal, simply use something like the following code in your *extension.js* file:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
    appAPI.pageAction.setPages({
        pages: ["*.google.com/*", /^http\:\/\/twitter\.com/],
        iconResourcePath:'icons/icon.jpg',
        html: '<html><head></head><body>Hello World!</body></html>',
        height: 100,
        width: 300
    });
});
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]